# Insertion into Oracle 11g happens inspite of readOnly=true for @Transactional

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm inserting values in Oracle 11g via hibernateSessionFactory LocalSessionFactoryBean injected via Spring config file.
Insert method of DAO class has @Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true). Method used to insert is org.hibernate.Session.persist and flush
Why is insertion happenning though readOnly=true for the transaction?

Thanks in advance,
Kakoli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [the javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#readOnly--):

> public abstract boolean readOnly
>
> true if the transaction is read-only. Defaults to false.
>
> This just serves as a hint for the actual transaction subsystem; it will not necessarily cause failure of write access attempts. A transaction manager which cannot interpret the read-only hint will not throw an exception when asked for a read-only transaction.